# Problem with update android app silently without user interaction and root permission

Tags: android, auto-update, silent-installer, packageinstaller

I know there is many stack-overflow posts for this question, but i couldn't solve my problem using any of them.
My app is only available for a limited group of people(inner company app), so i can't publish it in an app store and i want it to be updated automatically when i release a new version on the app server.
it is a `device admin` app with no root permission. i found [this](https://www.sisik.eu/blog/android/dev-admin/update-app) approach to achieve this goal but it didn't work.

I have this permission in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file to install packages:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

This is my code:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private void installPackage(Context context, String filePath, String packageName)
        throws IOException
{
    Log.d(TAG, "installPackage: start");
    PackageInstaller packageInstaller = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
    PackageInstaller.SessionParams params = new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(
            PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL);
    params.setAppPackageName(packageName);
    // set params
    int sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(params);
    PackageInstaller.Session session = packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId);
    //
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
    OutputStream out = session.openWrite(packageName, 0, -1);
    IOUtils.copyStream(in, out);
    //
    session.fsync(out);
    in.close();
    out.close();
    //
    session.commit(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 112233, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT).getIntentSender());
    Log.d(TAG, "installPackage: commit");
}
```

And this is `onCreate` method of my `MainActivity` class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, AdminReceiver.class);
    DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    if (getIntent() != null && dpm != null)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: is app admin : " + dpm.isAdminActive(componentName));
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: status : " + getIntent().getIntExtra("android.content.pm.extra.STATUS", 1000));
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: intent : " + getIntent().getParcelableExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT"));
    }
}
```

and this is my `logcat` result :

```
2019-07-08 15:03:24.147 5841-5841/com.test.learncheshmak D/AutoUpdateHelper: downloadUpdate: SUCCESSFUL
2019-07-08 15:03:24.147 5841-5841/com.test.learncheshmak D/AutoUpdateHelper: installPackage: start
2019-07-08 15:03:24.295 5841-5841/com.test.learncheshmak D/AutoUpdateHelper: installPackage: commit
2019-07-08 15:03:24.298 5841-5895/com.test.learncheshmak V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 11740
2019-07-08 15:03:24.302 5841-5841/com.test.learncheshmak W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@fe51cb8
2019-07-08 15:03:24.307 5841-5841/com.test.learncheshmak V/FA: onActivityCreated
2019-07-08 15:03:24.308 5841-5895/com.test.learncheshmak V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2019-07-08 15:03:24.308 5841-5841/com.test.learncheshmak D/MainActivity: onCreate: is app admin : true
2019-07-08 15:03:24.309 5841-5841/com.test.learncheshmak D/MainActivity: onCreate: status : -1
2019-07-08 15:03:24.309 5841-5841/com.test.learncheshmak D/MainActivity: onCreate: intent : Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.CONFIRM_PERMISSIONS pkg=com.google.android.packageinstaller (has extras) }
```

Here, as we see, status is -1. according to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller.html#STATUS_PENDING_USER_ACTION) document i got `STATUS_PENDING_USER_ACTION` and it determine we need user prompt to update our app.but this app is a device admin(device owner) app and according to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller.html) document:

> Committing may require user intervention to complete the installation, unless the caller falls into one of the following categories, in which case the installation will complete automatically.
>
> - the device owner
> - the affiliated profile owner

so if app be `device owner` install progress will perform automatically (with out user prompt). then why do i get `STATUS_PENDING_USER_ACTION` while my app is a `device admin` app?

Comment: I'm also facing to this issue, but only for API 21. For higher versions it works fine.